# How to set tab order for html from horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a multiple  form, contains 2 input boxes and a submit button. i have given tab order for each input. i have tab index for each input type. tab order is moving vertically than horizontally . it should go to first input box , second input box and then submit button.

Below is the code.

```
<form class="monitorForm" >
  <div class="monitorAdd">
    textbox1  <input type="text" tabindex="1">
    textbox2  <input type="text" tabindex="2">
        <input type="button" tabindex="3" value="submit">
  </div>
</form>
<form class="monitorForm">
    <div class="monitorAdd">
        textbox1        <input type="text" tabindex="1">
        textbox2        <input type="text" tabindex="2">
        <input type="button" tabindex="3" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
<form  class="monitorForm">
    <div class="monitorAdd">
          textbox1        <input type="text" tabindex="1">
          textbox2        <input type="text" tabindex="2">
         <input type="button" tabindex="3" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

below is the js code

```
$('form').each(function(){

    var list  = $(this).find('*[tabindex]').sort(function(a,b){ return a.tabIndex <      b.tabIndex ? -1 : 1; }),
    first = list.first();
    list.last().on('keydown', function(e){
        if( e.keyCode === 9 ) {
            first.focus();
            return false;
         }
    });
});
```

its a dynamic form which is coming in loop and contains many fields. i want to give tab order for only 3 input fields.

http://jsfiddle.net/mWLtp/5/

Please help me in solving this issue.
Thank in advance.

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/2MmP8/)

Comment: @pushpa : remove js code and remove tabindex attribute, it will work horizontal, you dont need to do anything for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery Way`  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/FK7Xe/4/)

```
var index = 1;

$("form input").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("tabindex", index);
    index++;
});
```

`HTML WAY` Well You Can Directly Give Tabindex  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/FK7Xe/1/)

```
<form class="monitorForm" >
    <div class="monitorAdd">
        textbox1        <input type="text" tabindex="1">
        textbox2        <input type="text" tabindex="2">
        <input type="button" tabindex="3" value="submit">
     </div>
</form>
<form class="monitorForm">
    <div class="monitorAdd">
        textbox1        <input type="text" tabindex="4">
        textbox2        <input type="text" tabindex="5">
        <input type="button" tabindex="6" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
<form  class="monitorForm">
    <div class="monitorAdd">
          textbox1        <input type="text" tabindex="7">
          textbox2        <input type="text" tabindex="8">
         <input type="button" tabindex="9" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

**well, if you dont define a tabindex attribute it defaults to horizontal, you dont need any tabindex or jquery**

Comment: Thank you. i think, i can use jquery way of adding tabindex. coz its a dynamic form which is coming in loop and contains many fields. i want to given order for only 3 input fields. so i cant give individual index value in HTML.

Comment: what if want vertical tab index using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
set distinct tab index. for your case set it in 1 t0 9.


Like

<form class="monitorForm" >
 <div class="monitorAdd">
    textbox1        <input type="text" tabindex="1">
    textbox2        <input type="text" tabindex="2">
    <input type="button" tabindex="3" value="submit">
 </div>
</form>
<form class="monitorForm">
<div class="monitorAdd">
    textbox1        <input type="text" tabindex="4">
    textbox2        <input type="text" tabindex="5">
    <input type="button" tabindex="6" value="submit">
</div> 
</form>
<form  class="monitorForm">
<div class="monitorAdd">
      textbox1        <input type="text" tabindex="7">
      textbox2        <input type="text" tabindex="8">
     <input type="button" tabindex="9" value="submit">
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: its a dynamic form which is coming in loop and contains many fields. i want to give tab order for only 3 input fields.

Answer (score 0):

All the `tabindex=1` will be taken in order from top to bottom, no matter if you have placed them in single `<div>` or different. Then will come the turn of `tabindex=2`.

Your Solution:

Change the tabindex like 1,2,3,4,5,6.. instead of 1,2,3,1,2,3,...

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Give to individual tabindex value,instead of `override` your tabindex value.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mWLtp/5/)

Comment: its a dynamic form which is coming in loop and contains many fields. i want to give tab order for only 3 input fields.